# Zooming to ArcGIS JavaScript API graphic feature, but not to full extent?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, extents

I have a Python based geoprocessing service that gets called in my web app. The web app takes a few input parameters, and zooms to a returned buffered section of cable that meets the criteria. This all works really great.

I'm using the following code to zoom to the returned graphic feature:

```
map.setExtent(graphicsUtils.graphicsExtent(map.graphics.graphics));
```

But, I really don't want the map to zoom this close to the graphic:

[image: No]

I'd prefer something like this:

[image: Yes]

Comment: In Python I would do something like `df.extent = df.extent * 2.5` so I'm guessing `map.setExtent = map.getExtent * 2.5` (with no JavaScript knowledge claimed).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried `map.setExtent(graphicsUtils.graphicsExtent(map.graphics.graphics) * 2);` but it doesn't seem to like it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the [Extent class](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/extent-amd.html) there's an [expand(factor) method](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/extent-amd.html#expand):

[image]

So, I tried:

```
var extent = graphicsUtils.graphicsExtent(map.graphics.graphics).expand(4)
map.setExtent(extent);
```

And it's exactly what I wanted.